# How to hide a component if there is no result found in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, search, filtering

In my Home page, I have a search bar and imported three components. my search bar have the ability to search through them but just wondering how can I hide a particular component if a result in not found in that component and only show a component that have a result.

The problem I have right now is, if search result is only found in Application group component then, the attachment and training component is showing me blank (pls check uploaded image below). I just want to hide the components that don't have the result while user is filtering/searching and just show it back the component when a user cancel the search.

I would be really appreciated if I can get help or suggestion on this.

```
    <!-- attachments -->
    <div>
      <app-attachment [attachments]="entity.attachments"></app-attachment>
    </div>
    <!-- appgroups -->
    <div *ngFor="let entityGroup of entity.entityGroups">
      <app-application-group [entityGroup]="entityGroup" [entity]="entity"></app-application-group>
    </div>

    <!-- Training and Support -->
    <div>
      <app-training [entity]="entity"></app-training>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchText$ = this.searchService.searchText
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(debounceTime(750), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.filterValue = value;
        this.loadApplication(this.entityType, this.entityId);
      });

    this.collapse = false;
    this.expanded = true;
    this.route.url.subscribe((_value) => {
      this.entityType = BaseEntity.stringToType(_value[0].path);
      this.entityId = Number(_value[1].path);
      this.loadApplication(this.entityType, this.entityId);
      this.populateMeetups(this.entityId);
    });
  }

  loadApplication(entityType: EntityType, entityId: number): void {
    this.color = BaseEntity.color(this.entityType);
    if (this.entityType && this.entityId) {
      // this.filterValue = null;
      this.childrenActive = null;
      this.pageSize = 999;
      this.childrenActive = true; // We want to bring only active children for things that have tables.
    }
    this.entityService
      .getApplicationDetails(
        entityId,
        entityType,
        this.pageSize,
        this.childrenActive,
        this.filterValue,
      )
      .subscribe((entity) => {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.ancestor = this.entity.channels.get(0);
        this.entityGroup = this.entity.entityGroups.filter(
          (r) => r.entityType === EntityType.Application,
        );
        this.entity.attachments = this.entity.attachments.filter((app) => {
          return app.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterValue.toLowerCase());
        });
      });
  }
```

[click here to view my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL8sB.png)

Comment: I think you can throw some *ngIf's in there. For instance `<div *ngIf="entity?.attachments?.length > 0">` above the `app-attachment` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *ngIf to remove stuff from the DOM you don't want to show. For example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="entity.attachments?.length">
  <div>
    <app-attachment [attachments]="entity.attachments"></app-attachment>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Or hide it with css:

```
<div [ngClass]="entity.attachments?.length ? 'show' : 'hide'">
  <app-attachment [attachments]="entity.attachments"></app-attachment>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

You may want to consider placing the *ngIf inside the child component instead of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ngIf by checking the length of the search result instead of creating a new variable. Also use else block to display no result found  as shown below

Show result here 


No result found .